# replacing rows in empty (NA) data frame without converting factors to integer

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I have a data frame of NA values and specified dimensions, and I am trying to replace the rows in that data frame with the rows from other data frames, but the replacement rows have several data types, and the factors keep getting converted to integers. How do I stop this?

```
#Example
df.na <- data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=2,ncol=3)) #data frame of NA values
df <- cbind.data.frame(c("a","b"),c(1,2),c(TRUE,FALSE)) #data frame of values I want
df.na[1,] <- df[1,] #replace row 1
str(df.na) #column one is now an integer not a factor
```

The purpose behind this is that it is part of a for loop, and I'm using the indexing to replace rows as I go (each iteration generates a row) rather than building the data frame one iteration at a time.

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent conversion to integer by not using a `factor` in the first place, but `character`, using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`:

```
df.na <- data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=2,ncol=3))
df <- cbind.data.frame(c("a","b"),c(1,2),c(TRUE,FALSE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df.na[1,] <- df[1,]
df.na
#     X1 X2   X3
# 1    a  1 TRUE
# 2 <NA> NA   NA
```

If you need the column as factor, use

```
df.na[, 1] <- factor(df.na[, 1])
```

But usually this is not necessary I guess.